# Человек, который часто берет «погонять» вещи

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, жаргон

Как по-заумному называть человека, который часто берет вещи на время «погонять»?

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен отражать его суть.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а что означает "погонять" в данном контексте?

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Попользоваться (сленг).

Answer (score 2):

*Зашкварный халявщик, чайка неуемная.* Достаточно заумно?